# An extension of the term 'anthropomorphism' to 'cultural anthropomorphism', or is there a better term?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, language-evolution

We are perhaps familiar with the definition of 'anthropomorphism' as the assignment of human characteristics and culture to animals, or perhaps to gods.

Something that is happening more and more in the zeitgeist today, in our multinational world, is the assignment of the properties of one culture to another, and therefore treating that culture as if it were identical to your own. Sort of the inevitable result of the application of the Golden Rule - "Do onto others as you would have then do onto you'. If their culture is entirely different from yours, they might not WANT you to treat them the way you want to be treated. Individual respect vs. family respect, for instance. One culture might believe that treating you as an individual separate from your family is important, and another culture might consider that an individual should ALWAYS supplicate to notions of family respect and family integrity. I have posited that the Golden Rule should be 'Do onto others the way they want you to do onto them', requiring you to understand their culture, and treat them according to their culture, not try to force them to work within your culture.

It seems to me that recognizing the issue of imposing one's cultural perspective on a different culture, and thereby leading to misunderstandings, is becoming more and more important, particularly with the rise of many other non-Western cultures to the same economic stature as the West, and the inevitable Thucydides Paradox.

I am thinking especially about the tendency of the West to treat South Asia as if they had the same ideals of freedom and social responsibility as the West. Treating South Asia as if it's population had identical goals to that of America can only lead to tremendous friction and total lack of any basis for mutual understanding.

But before we can have a common dialogue over the problem, we need to have clearly recognized and understood terms for it. My argument has been that lacking any other term, this in fact should be referred to as 'cultural anthropomorphism' - the imposing of the characteristics of one's own culture onto another, so as to not have to understand the other culture. The English language has always demonstrated a capacity for 'evolving' one term to meet newer requirements, when an existing term does not seem to be adequate.

Thus the question, "Is there a recognized term for the process of attributing and projecting the characteristics of one culture onto another such that the other culture is completely misrepresented, or in fact would the term 'cultural anthropomorphizing' suffice?"

In point of fact, I want to acknowledge that intentionally comparing all other cultures to your culture, and then assuming that any cultural differences are due to the other culture being inferior to your culture, is the inherent basis of racism. I am wiling to consider that there is too much bag-and-baggage culturally assigned to the term 'anthropomorphising' to preclude this. Yet I hardly think attributing human characteristics to a god, or assigning the characteristics of a god to humans, is necessarily degrading, as much as it is narcissistic. Can a term evolve beyond its existing bag-and-baggage?

Certainly the term 'decimate' has left its bag-and-baggage behind a long time ago.

**ADDENDUM**

Based on feedback, I feel an elaboration is required. Pease bear with me.

For the sake of illustration, I am going to coin the placeholder term **quarvineanism** and define it as follows: *"The ascription of one's own cultural attributes to other cultures; in theology, the conception or representation of God with one's own culture's qualities and affections, or in the guise of your own culture and ethnicity".* (An example of the later, God and Jesus are always portrayed as being White Americans and using American mannerisms and gestures in American culture).

Here is a real-life scenario and example. In the Japanese culture, when two businessmen meet, it is considered good manners to get as close the the other person as possible, within inches of their face in fact. It shows sincerity and honesty, and is a sign of deep respect. In Western culture, it is considered good manners to give the other person their personal space, and not to invade it. Getting too close is a sign of disrespect and domination. When a Japanese and Western businessman meet, an external observer sees a predictable, almost comical, dance. The Japanese person will try to come as close as possible, while the American will be continually backing off and withdrawing, all around the meeting space. One might consider the Japanese representative as aggressive, and the American as timid. They each consider the other person as 'rude' and 'disrespectful', the Japanese businessman feeling the American is refusing the offers of mutual respect, the American feeling the Japanese is not respecting personal boundaries and is trying to intimidate. Neither is following normal social convention as perceived by the other, but perfectly following their own culture's mores. They each leave with a nagging feeling of distrust for the other. They are both **quarvineanizing**, expecting the other to conform to their own cultural mores. They are subconsciously and reflexively trying to treat the other person as they want to be treated - with respect. The ultimate dystopian trap of following the Golden Rule. The cultural mores for 'respect' are completely opposite in each case, making the Golden Rule completely contradictory and adversarial, giving exactly the opposite intended results. No matter how well-meaning each participant is, no matter how sincerely each tries to reach out to the other with a show of respect, the interaction goes downhill very quickly. The harder each tries to correct it, the more damage is done.

Neither had any intention of judging or evaluating the other person's culture. In fact, they are both expecting the other person to react according to their own culture. They each desperately want to treat the other with full respect and equality. If they both understood they were **quarvineanizing**, they would have a much smoother interaction, and realize that neither was intentionally trying to be 'rude' or 'obstinate' or any such negative term. However, without a proper term for the scenario, it is very difficult to formalize it, identify it, and counter it.

I am sure that in diplomatic circles, this is clearly understood,  discussed, and trained for. It is all part of the pre-preparation planning. One never extends one's hand to the Queen, and one never walks in front of her. For Trump to do so, he came across as an 'uncouth, undisciplined, uncivil American' in the eyes of the British. Yet from Trump's narcissistic American viewpoint, it was perfectly natural.

Now, the accepted definition for **anthropomorphism** is: *"The ascription of human attributes to supernatural or divine beings; in theology, the conception or representation of God with human qualities and affections, or in a human shape."*

My query is: Is there enough wiggle room within the definition of **anthropomorphism** to allow the term to evolve so as to cover the definition of "**quarvineanism**", given the extreme similarity of definitions between them (as per my example of how drastically the definition of '*decimate*' has changed) or is there an existing term that has the same definition of "**quarvineanism**", or a term that can be modified to suit, or do we need an entirely new term "**quarvineanism**"? The only difference between the definitions is to replace the qualifiers 'human' with 'cultural' and 'supernatural or divine or inanimate' with 'another culture'.

Comment: I am almost certain that such a word has already been coined.  This concept you're exploring - a critique of pseudo-universalist-but-really-subjective ideas - has occupied an important place in postmodern discourse since the mid-20th century.  The aspect that you're focusing on is a focus of postcolonial studies.  It's been a while since I read it, but you might find the word you're looking for in Dipesh Chakrabarty's "Provincializing Europe."  I might call this phenomenon "universality ethnocentrism."  If you use those as search terms in Google, you can tune into the ongoing debate about it.

Comment: @Juhasz If such a word has been coined, then what is it? It is not related to ethnicity, so much as it is related to culture.  The terms 'culture' and 'ethnicity' are no longer interchangeable. "The term ethnocentrism passed from social science theory into common English usage during the twentieth century. In present usage it means the belief that one’s culture is superior to others the use of a frame of reference derived from one’s own culture to judge the arrtibutes of another culture, often in disparaging terms." it is the avoidance of 'disparaging' that I am after.

Comment: Previous quote from https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/social-sciences/ethnocentrism I am after a more neutral term.

Comment: Ethnocentrism describes WHY we do it, usually making a value judgement on it, but it does not describe the process of WHAT we do. It does not cover the 'projecting one's culture onto another' aspect I am after. It COMPARES cultures.

Comment: Whatever the right term for this phenomenon might be, it is most definitely **not** any version of *anthropomorphism*, as using that term would imply that one thinks the people on the other side of the cultural divide are not really human beings.

Comment: @Justin Ethnocentrism definitely is the 'what'. It's definitely not about comparing, but of assuming everyone follows your cultural ideals. I would upvote it as an answer. I came here to wonder aloud if 'projection' we're appropriate for cultures (not just individuals).

Comment: Any phrase with anthropomorphism in it is going to be wrong.  Anthropomorphism is a distinct concept and is unrelated to the situation you describe. I would endorse Juhasz's "ethnocentrism". OED: **The state or quality of being ethnocentric.** -- 1906   W. G. Sumner Folkways i. 13   *Ethnocentrism is the technical name for this view of things in which one's own group is the center of everything, and all others are scaled and rated with reference to it.*

Comment: @Greybeard by your supplied definition, ethnocentrism has just as much a derogatory connotation as some are implying anthropomorphism has. Ethnocentric implies that you recognize the other person has a different culture, it is just that the culture is inferior to yours. I am after a term where the observer ASSUMES the other culture is EXACTKY the same, neither inferior nor superior, because it is not different, just as anthropomorphism assumes the other 'target' is exactly like the observer in all aspects. Children do not see their dolls as inferior, but equals.

Comment: @Mitch Much has been written on the term 'projection' vs 'anthropomorphism'. The same arguments against using 'projection' for 'anthropomorphism' apply here. From my understanding of the philosophy behind ethnocentrism, as per your definition, it is used to RATE your culture against another culture, it does not attempt to define both cultures as being the same. In anthropomorphism, there is no sense of rating different cultures, they are assumed to be equal and identical.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond *by your supplied definition, ethnocentrism has just as much a derogatory connotation as some are implying anthropomorphism has.* I do not know how you have understood that I implied that. **Ethnocentrism** and **anthropomorphism** are neutral. *I am after a term where the observer ASSUMES the other culture is EXACTLY the same,"* -- * **Ethnocentrism** does that. --*1906   W. G. Sumner:   Ethnocentrism is the technical name for this view of things in which one's own group is the center of everything, and all others are scaled and rated with reference to it.*

Comment: @Greybeard  "and all others are scaled and rated with reference to it." How can this phrase NOT imply that the other culture is being rated and scaled against one's own culture? Ethnocentrism is the epitome of cultural narcissism.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond. Forgive me. With your comment; *Ethnocentrism is the epitome of cultural narcissism,* you seem to be pursuing some political agenda devoid of linguistic content. It is simply not true. The human mind has nothing against which to judge, save for that which it knows.

Comment: @Greybeard The term 'narcissism' has definitely been corrupted in populist culture. From Wikipedia "Narcissism, in and of itself, is a normal personality trait, however, high levels of narcissistic behavior can be damaging and self-defeating.[15] Destructive narcissism is the constant exhibition of a few of the intense characteristics usually associated with pathological Narcissistic personality disorder. On a spectrum, destructive narcissism is more extreme than common narcissism but not as extreme as the pathological condition.[16]"

Comment: What is quoted here (from where?) as 'the accepted definition for *anthropomorphism*' applies only to certain contexts; the question systematically ignores the fact that the term is also used for attributing human characteristics to animals and inanimate objects, and that using the term in the way that is proposed would therefore have highly offensive implications.

Comment: @jsw29 From my definition "...the assignment of human characteristics and culture to animals" from your quote ..."the term is also used for attributing human characteristics to animals". I fail to see the difference, except tat I included the term 'culture'. Can you please elaborate?.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the idea of a hegemon professing the assimilation of conquered areas due to perceived cultural superiority is new. This was common in the Roman Empire, the various Caliphates, and *especially* east Asia by whatever dynasty controlled the area of modern China. The more modern examples are more ideological than cultural, but ultimately result from dissonance between cultures, how people should be governed, religion, etc. While I don't think a more exact term to describe the situation exists, I would say that it falls under what I would term as cultural dissension.

Comment: I think (cultural) antagonism more fits what your looking for, but didn't include it in the answer because I believe it misses the nuance presented by the root reasoning, rather than the conflict itself.

Comment: The term I am looking for makes the assumption that there is NO difference between the cultures, that both cultures are exactly the same. That whatever one's own culture considers good, so to does the other culture.  The term would encompass a sense of denial that there is any difference in the  cultures at all. Anthropomorphism implies that the target is EXACTLY culturally the same, that the target is an identical human to the observer, a total denial that there is any difference. There is no denigration in anthropomorphism.

Comment: In point of fact, your answer is an example of exactly what I am looking for - treating ALL societies as if they were the same, that they all follow a common script that you define.

Comment: The down vote was NOT mine, I find your answer useful and insightful.